# Close browser completely with selenium C# webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am doing some automated testing with Selenium C# Webdriver. And after finishing the tests I want to close the browser.

I initialize the driver with the following:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

And then after doing something I am closing it with

```
driver.Close();
```

The browser is correcly closes, but there is a window which starts this browser which is still hanging.[image]

Is there a way to close it as well?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`driver.Close()` is intended to close popup browser windows, such as those opened by clicking on a link that triggers a `window.open()` call in JavaScript. To be absolutely certain all resources are released and cleaned up by a driver, use `driver.Quit()`.

Answer (score 7):

This will close browser window as well as Chrome Driver prompt

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```

Comment: this is not working for me :/

Answer (score 4):

Always use Driver.Quit(); to close WebDriver and browser

`Driver.Quit();`